# I'm trying to update a table and call another row from different table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert-update, multiple-tables

This query is supposed to only update points in `csp` table once the status is 3. the status is from a different table. I come up with an error. what did I do wrong with the coding here?

```
$sql_update_csp= "UPDATE csp SET ttlpoints = (ttlpoint+$point)" ;

$sql_update_earn =$sql_update_csp."WHERE xid='$xid' AND status='3'" ;
```

Comment: replace `"WHERE` with `" WHERE`

Comment: `$sql_update_earn = "UPDATE csp SET ttlpoints = (ttlpoint+$point) WHERE xid='$xid' AND status='3';"` try with this. 
The question is `status` column is in the csp table or not?

Comment: if not the you need to make a join and then where

Comment: status column is in earn_act table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE c SET c.ttlpoints = (c.ttlpoint+$point)
from csp c
left join earn_act ea
on c.column_name = ea.column_name
WHERE c.xid='$xid' AND ea.status='3'
```

where `column_name` will the be the column used for joining the 2 tables, like primary key and foreign key.

Hope this helps.

Comment: will i be able to use this code if both column dont have the same row? lets say 'xid' is in csp table but not in b table. is it still possible to use this code?

Comment: if i want to put a condition to this query like status has to be '3' then only  ttlpoints+$points will execute. but status is from earn_act table.  this is the code i have right now... if ($row[`xid']! = ' ')  {  $sql_update_csp= "UPDATE csp SET ttlpoints =(ttlpoints+$point) where xid='$xid'" ;          how do i fix this

Comment: In that case it will not work, you can first check the the status in earn_act table and then use just update the points in csp table.

I assume you can do something like this
Query to get the status from earn_act table then
    if(status == 3){
      Your update query
    }

Comment: thank you muzaffar sir. i think I will try to do that i just started learning php. i'll update if it work